# android animation incorrectly animating

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a top level LinearLayout that has many children composed of a button followed by an invisible LinearLayout. When I press the button, I would like the contents of the LinearLayout to animate and press everything down smoothly. Instead what is happening is a big white space is instantly being carved out and then the LinearLayout animates into the empty space instead of everything being gracefully pushed down.

My onCreate method creates the massive LinearList plus all the children of each child LinearList. If you run this code you will see 20 buttons labled "Button X" where X is 0-19. When you click on a button indented buttons animate below (like a sub menu) but the next button in the form of "Button X+1" is immediately painted all the way down and not animated being pushed down.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout topll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.topll);

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Button"+String.format("%s", i));
        b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        topll.addView(b);

        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
        l.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for(int k=0; k<10; k++)
        {
            Button b2 = new Button(this);
            b2.setText("New Button"+String.format("%s", k));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
            p.setMargins(80, 0, 0, 0);
            b2.setLayoutParams(p);
            //b2.setOnClickListener(this);
            l.addView(b2);
        }

        topll.addView(l);
    }


}
```

And here is my method that gets called when a button is pushed...

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        LinearLayout topll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.topll);

    for(int i=0;i<topll.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        if(topll.getChildAt(i) == arg0)
        {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)topll.getChildAt(i+1);
            if(ll.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.expanddown);
                ll.setAnimation(animation);
                animation.start();
                ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.expandup);
                ll.setAnimation(animation);
                animation.start();
                ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally my animation xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:duration="1000" 
        android:startOffset="0" 
        android:fillAfter="false" 
        android:fromXScale="1.0" 
        android:fromYScale="0.0" 
        android:toYScale="1.0" 
        android:toXScale="1.0" 
        android:pivotY="0%"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all use

```
ll.startAnimation(animation);
```

instead of :

```
ll.setAnimation(animation);
animation.start();
```

then use an animation listener and

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim)
                    {
                    };
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim)
                    {
                    };
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)
                    {
                        ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // or what ever
                    };
                });
```

Comment: that doesn't work when I tried it. The result was that I press the button, a second goes by and then everything appears. I tried putting the ll.setVisibility call in the onAnimationStart, but that resulted in my original problem.